# How to pass word2vec embedding as a Keras Embedding layer?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, data-science, word2vec

I am solving a multi-class classification problem using Keras. But I am assuming the accuracy is bad due to poor word embedding of my data (domain-specific data).

Keras has its own Embedding layer, which is a supervised learning method.

So I have 2 questions regarding this :

1. Can I use word2vec embedding in Embedding layer of Keras, because word2vec is a form of unsupervised learning/self-supervised?
2. If yes, then can I use transfer learning on word2vec pre-train model to put extra knowledge of my domain specific features.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the embeddings layer with word2vec or any other pre-trained embeddings (maybe [FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText)?) in such a way that you manually construct the embedding matrix, i.e., just load all the numbers form the word2vec files and make an `np.array` of it. Then you create a [constant initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/Constant) and pass it as an argument to your embeddings layer constructor.

If you don't want the embeddings to get updated during training, just set `trainable` to `False` on the layer object.